# I can't type any character in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

When I try to edit my code I can't do it, I've got a "fat" cursor on the text and also when I try to mark and delete text it's impossible
[image: a]

[image]

Comment: try it. File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would guess the reason for this is that you've accidentally installed the IdeaVim plugin. The commands of this are the same as vim. Try pressing the `i` key to enter insert mode. Is this worked, then remove the IdeaVim plugin from Android Studio (pressing right shift twice and removing the plugin). You can also uncheck `Enable` when you press on the IdeaVim icon on the lower right of your editor.

Comment: this isn't caused by plugins, it's just the insert key

Comment: With the insert key, it would still be possible to mark and delete text.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be like you have install IdeaVim Plugin. Please disable or remove the plugin. Your problem will be solve. I had same issue

Answer (score 0):

Go to `File` > `Invalidate Caches` > `Invalidate and Restart`

Answer (score 0):

I encounter this situation too and I resolve it by this command on Mac:

```
 rm ~/Library/Preferences/com.google.android.studio.plist
```